# How do I use an array in a if parented by a for loop in java?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am trying to loop through the colors in my array using a for loop and IF the array gets to the 'orange' then have it break the loop.
Here is my code(I'm only two weeks into coding, please educate me - Also if you can find a solution not only in javascript but jQuery too that would be great! help my spirit ) :

```
var button = document.querySelector("button")
var gifs = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange'];

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for (i = 0; i < gifs.length; i++) {
        // document.body.style.background = gifs[i];
        if ( gifs.length[2] = true) {
            console.log("its GOOD");
            else {
                console.log("ITS NOT GOOD");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to know when you're on the last array iteration? `i === gifs.length-1`. Or specifically on `2`, then `i === 2`. Or specifically on `orange`, then `gifs[i] === "orange"`

Comment: Seeing that you have code there that sets the `.background`, I'd bet you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: you want to know when the last element is reached or when `orange` is reached?

Answer (score 0):

> IF the array gets to the 'orange' then have it break the loop

- To break a `for-loop` you need to use the keyword `break`.
- To loop over an array, you need to use an index, in this case: `gifs[i]`

**This is an example to illustrate how to break and loop an array:**

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var gifs = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange'];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < gifs.length; i++) {    
    if (gifs[i] === 'orange') {
      document.body.style.background = gifs[i];
      break;
    } else {
      console.log("ITS NOT GOOD");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```